# Migrating Recaptcha to invisible Recaptcha

Tags: php, ajax, validation, invisible-recaptcha

## Background

I,ve implemented a recpatcha solucion from this site http://phppot.com/php/php-contact-form-with-google-recaptcha/

Now I want to migrate to Invisible Recaptcha, but I can't validate with the PHP module.

I'm using PHP library for recaptcha https://github.com/google/recaptcha

## Ask

I want to migrate to Invisible Recaptcha, but I can't validate with sender.php. How can I add data-callback with this validation method?. Then, how perform only recaptcha PHP verification with ajax?, so challenge should appear after the input validation

## Working Code site with Recaptcha (no invisible)

### index.php

```
    <?php
    require('constant.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="component/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e){
            $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#mail-status").hide();
                $('#send-message').hide();
                $('#loader-icon').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "sender.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType:'json',
                    data: {
                    "name":$('input[name="name"]').val(),
                    "email":$('input[name="email"]').val(),
                    "phone":$('input[name="phone"]').val(),
                    "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
                    "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()},             
                    success: function(response){
                    $("#mail-status").show();
                    $('#loader-icon').hide();
                    if(response.type == "error") {
                        $('#send-message').show();
                        $("#mail-status").attr("class","error");                
                    } else if(response.type == "message"){
                        $('#send-message').hide();
                        $("#mail-status").attr("class","success");                          
                    }
                    $("#mail-status").html(response.text);  
                    },
                    error: function(){} 
                });
            }));
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        ...  
        </style>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <form id="frmContact" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
           ...
           <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>"></div>
           ...
        </form>
         ...
    </body>
    </html>
```

### sender.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if($_POST)
{
require('constant.php');

    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_phone     = filter_var($_POST["phone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $content   = filter_var($_POST["content"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(empty($user_name)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Name</b>";       
    }
    if(empty($user_email)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Email</b>";
    }
    if(empty($user_phone)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Phone Number</b>";
    }   
    if(empty($content)) {
        $empty[] = "<b>Comments</b>";
    }

    if(!empty($empty)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' Required!'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$user_email.'</b> is an invalid Email, please correct it.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //reCAPTCHA validation
    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

        require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');        

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

          if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
                $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Validation Required!'));
                die($output);               
          } 
    }

    $toEmail = MAIL_TO;
    $mailHeaders = "From: " . $user_name . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";
    if (mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $content, $mailHeaders)) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .', thank you for the comments. We will get back to you shortly.'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email, please contact'.SENDER_EMAIL));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

## Almost working code with Invisible ReCaptcha

The followin code works with Invisible recaptcha but I need to perform validation input first by PHP, and then ask for recaptcha challenge. Like the original code.

### index.php

```
<?php
require('constant.php');
?>
...
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>

    <script>    
    var onloadCallback = function(){
        grecaptcha.render("emplacementRecaptcha",{
            "sitekey": "<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>",
            "badge": "inline",
            "type": "image",
            "size": "invisible",
            "callback": onSubmit
        });
    };
    var onSubmit = function(token){     
        $("#mail-status").hide();
        $('#send-message').hide();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "sender.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
            "name":$('input[name="name"]').val(),
            "email":$('input[name="email"]').val(),
            "phone":$('input[name="phone"]').val(),
            "content":$('textarea[name="content"]').val(),
            "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()},             
            success: function(response){
            $("#mail-status").show();
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            if(response.type == "error") {
                $('#send-message').show();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","error");
                grecaptcha.reset();
            } else if(response.type == "message"){
                $('#send-message').hide();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","success");                          
            }
            $("#mail-status").html(response.text);  
            },
            error: function(){
                grecaptcha.reset();
                $("#mail-status").html("Error en la funcion");
            } 
        });             
    };
    function validate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#mail-status").html("Validacion recaptcha en curso");
        grecaptcha.execute();
    }
    function onload(){
        var element = document.getElementById("send-message");
        element.onclick = validate;
    }   
    </script>

    <style>
    .label {margin: 2px 0;}
    .field {margin: 0 0 20px 0;}    
        .content {width: 960px;margin: 0 auto;}
        h1, h2 {font-family:"Georgia", Times, serif;font-weight: normal;}
        div#central {margin: 40px 0px 100px 0px;}
        @media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {.content {width: 750px;}}
        @media all and (max-width: 767px) {
            body {margin: 0 auto;word-wrap:break-word}
            .content {width:auto;}
            div#central {   margin: 40px 20px 100px 20px;}
        }
        body {font-family: 'Helvetica',Arial,sans-serif;background:#ffffff;margin: 0 auto;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;  font-size: initial;line-height: 1.7em;} 
        input, textarea {width:100%;padding: 15px;font-size:1em;border: 1px solid #A1A1A1;  }
        button {
            padding: 12px 60px;
            background: #5BC6FF;
            border: none;
            color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
            font-size:1em;
            font-family: "Georgia", Times, serif;
            cursor: pointer;    
        }
        #message {  padding: 0px 40px 0px 0px; }
        #mail-status {
            padding: 12px 20px;
            width: 100%;
            display:none; 
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: "Georgia", Times, serif;
            color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
        }
      .error{background-color: #F7902D;  margin-bottom: 40px;}
      .success{background-color: #48e0a4; }
        .g-recaptcha {margin: 0 0 25px 0;}    
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

...
        <form id="frmContact" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
            ...
            <div id="emplacementRecaptcha"></div>           
            ...         
            <button type="Submit" id="send-message" style="clear:both;">Send Message</button>
        </form>
        <script>onload();</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

### sender.php

No changes

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to migrate to Invisible Recaptcha, but I can't validate with sender.php. How can I add data-callback with this solution?

Comment: Do you want to validate if you will show the reCaptcha with some php code before it appears, right?

Comment: yes, validation with ajax and json php,